# Android http://10.0.2.2 automatically change into http://localhost on emulator?

Tags: android

I don't know why my `http://10.0.2.2/` changed into `http://localhost` in android emulator. In android browser on emulator I enter on address bar a link  `http://10.0.2.2/`. On first time I get the webpage form web server i.e WAMP. When I click some other link on that page then `http://10.0.2.2` gets change into `http://localhost/someotherlink/` and says webpage not available. Please solve my problem same thing happing with my app too.

Comment: It might be that the site being served on `http://10.0.2.2/` is (incorrectly) providing absolute links to `localhost` instead of relative links. What does the link to `/someotherlink/` look like in the page's source (if you view the source from a desktop browser, or in server-side source code)?

Comment: I us ’http://10.0.2.2/login.php’ an absolute path in my app.

Comment: No that is not an answer to @Steve 's question. I asked you already the same in your other post. Please answer questions to the point instead of starting a new post.

Comment: Solved it I changed webpage href to 10.0.2.2. Sorry for getting your point late.